# importing nltk in ironpython does not work after importing numpy

Tags: numpy, ironpython, nltk

I am trying to do part of speech tagging in ironpython. I have used the following code to do so in python2.6 which is working fine.

```
import nltk
text=nltk.word_tokenize("hello everyone")
nltk.pos_tag(text)
```

but when i try to do the same thing in ironpython i get the following

```
IronPython 2.7.1 (2.7.0.40) on .NET 4.0.30319.1
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
>>> text = nltk.word_tokenize("hello world")
>>> print text
['hello', 'world']
>>> nltk.pos_tag(text)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7.1\nltk\tag\__init__.py", line 63,
in pos_tag
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7.1\nltk\data.py", line 594, in load

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7.1\nltk\classify\maxent.py", line 5
6, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
>>>
```

when i installed numpy and scipy then i was not able to import nltk. It showed some attributeerror saying 'module' object -getframe().
then i removed numpy and scipy and i was able to import nltk.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add numpy and scipy back in. In order to prevent the "getframe" error, you need to pass a command-line parameter to ironpython that tells it to include support for frames:

```
ipy.exe -X:FullFrames
```

That should do the trick, and allow numpy to load.